# react native portrait images orientation incorrect

Tags: android, react-native

I'm having an issue where some (but oddly, not all) images that were taken as a portrait are displaying as landscape (appears rotated 90 degrees counter clockwise) in my react native app.

Other info:

- Android (I'm testing on galaxy s8+)
- Using `CameraRoll` to retrieve photos
- Using the default `<Image>` module
- I gave react-native-exif a try, but it's not as performant as I would like as I am rendering a lot of photos

Code snippets of what I'm doing to display images:

```
CameraRoll.getPhotos({
    first: 100, 
    assetType: 'Photos',
    mimeTypes: ['image/jpeg', 'image/png']
}).then(r => {
    this.setState(
        { 
          'photos': r.edges,
          'requesting_photos': false
        }
    );
})
```

...

```
// (using a flatlist)
_renderItem({item, index}) {
    return (
      <View style={{padding: 1, width: '25%'}}>
        <Image
            style={{flex: 1}}
            source={{ uri: item.node.image.uri }}
            fadeDuration={250}
        />
      </View>
    )
});
```

Thanks!